# How to pay for a traffic ticket I got in Italy?

Tags: italy, payment, fines

So I got a fine from when I was in Italy in a rented car. It happened in Parma, and I was directed by the letter to [their website](http://www.comune.parma.it/poliziamunicipale/COME-EFFETTUARE-IL-PAGAMENTO.aspx). There I can see two choices of online payment, by credit card or bank transfer. The credit card payment needs me to have an italian fiscal code, so I think I have to go with a bank transfer. However, I am not sure what to put in the transfer title, so that it gets processed correctly. Does anyone have a similar experience and can help me with advice?

I live in Poland, so I am in EU but not in eurozone.

Comment: Where are you now? (It likely makes a difference whether you're in the Single Euro Payment Area or not).

Comment: I checked your link but found no notion at first sight that you need a fiscal code. However note that you can easily obtain your fiscal code, e.g. here: https://www.professionegiustizia.it/calcoli/calcolo_codice_fiscale_estero - unlike e.g. social security numbers, it is not assigned (unless in rare cases) but computed from your name and date and place of birth.

Comment: @HenningMakholm right, I edited my question

Comment: @mts I tried to pay with credit card and last step before payment required a fiscal code. So I can obtain it even though I'm not in Italy? Is it active immediately or are there any extra steps?

Comment: As I said, you do not really obtain it, rather you should see it more as something you always had, you just only learn about it now. However you should make sure there is a different way they can link your payment to you, e.g. a case number or license plate number + date. If this already solves your question, I will post this as an answer.

Comment: @mts: That description is not entirely consistent with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_fiscal_code_card which states that even though there is an algorithm for deriving a _default_ code for a person, the code may need to be changed by the tax authorities to prevent two different people from having the same code.

Comment: There is almost always an option to pay such things by mailing them a cheque. You can probably get your bank to create a cheque for you in Euros. Then you just mail it to the address specified.

Comment: @HenningMakholm entirely true but these are rare exceptions. And in any case I assume they will have different means to match the payment to the fine and the codice fiscale is not strictly necessary. Note that it is commonly asked in all types of transactions in Italy, e.g. when returning bought stuff at IKEA.

Comment: @DJClayworth cheques are incredibly out-of-fashion in Italy (as in many other European countries, with the fancy exception of France). The linked website lists four payment options but not cheques. Someone in their collection office would need to make a huge manual effort for this and I find it unlikely to be a practical way.

Comment: Just because it asks for the fiscal code doesn't mean you can't just enter any number and proceed.

Comment: @JonathanReez: They will quite likely _receive the money_ in that case, but will they also recognize the OP's particular fine as paid?

Comment: @mts yes, the form in the link to credit card payment first asks for case number and license plate. I think this solves my question, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the only thing that keeps you from paying by credit card is a fiscal code (codice fiscale). Very strictly speaking this code is assigned to you by the Italian tax authorities, but as a practical matter it is easily derived from your name and date and place of birth. Many websites offer this, e.g. [this one](https://www.professionegiustizia.it/calcoli/calcolo_codice_fiscale_estero) does so for people born abroad (make sure to enter the **Italian** name of your country of birth). In rare cases when two people have the same codice fiscale, the code would need to be adjusted, but this should not be a concern to you as you state that you are also stating your case number and license plate.

Answer (score 3):

There is some (cryptical) reference or file number in the letter that you received (most probably on the top of the letter and doubled as bar code). Put that number into the transaction title.

(*that was what I did and the fine was fine*).